# Form Validation in Angular 2 (RC5) not working as expected

Tags: angular

I am having little trouble in implementing form validation in angular 2. Following are details.

1. Login.ts anf Login.html

```js
export class CpLogin {
    public User: Login=new Login();
    constructor() {        
    }
    DoLogin() {
    }
}
```

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="DoLogin()" #login="ngForm">
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="User.UserName" id="username" name="username" #uname="ngModel" required placeholder="Username" 
    maxLength="150" type="text" [dividerColor]="(!uname.valid || uname.pristine) ? 'accent':'primary'">
    </md-input>
    <div [hidden]="uname.valid || uname.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
        Username is required.
    </div>

    <md-input [(ngModel)]="User.Password" id="password" name="password" #password="ngModel" required placeholder="Password" 
    maxLength="150" type="password" [dividerColor]="(!password.valid || password.pristine) ? 'accent':'primary'">
    </md-input>
    <div [hidden]="password.valid || password.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
        Password is required.
    </div>
    <button type="submit" md-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!login.form.valid">Login</button>
</form>
```

Login form screenshot
[image]

Validation works fine except when login form is loaded username and password text is shown in red as for both username and password css class looks like below.

class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"

(Verified from developer tools). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in

```
[dividerColor]="(!uname.valid || uname.pristine) ? 'accent':'primary'"
```

which you need to change to

```
[dividerColor]="(!uname.valid && !uname.pristine) ? 'accent':'primary'"
```

Comment: Shouldn't class be class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" on initial load instead of class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"

Comment: Since it's `required`, and it's empty, it's invalid. Even in the beginning.